# discord.py TypeError: object Lock can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

please, help.
everything worked fine, but apparently something changed with some update.
I dont understand how to solve this problem
thanks for the help

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-28' coro=<MusicPlayer._play() done, defined at player.py:263 exception=TypeError("object Lock can't be used in 'await' expression")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "player.py", line 273, in _play
    with await self._play_lock:
TypeError: object Lock can't be used in 'await' expression
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-33' coro=<MusicPlayer._play() done, defined at player.py:263 exception=TypeError("object Lock can't be used in 'await' expression")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "player.py", line 273, in _play
    with await self._play_lock:
TypeError: object Lock can't be used in 'await' expression
```

```py
    async def _play(self, _continue=False):
        if self.is_paused and self._current_player:
            return self.resume()

        if self.is_dead:
            return

        with await self._play_lock:
            if self.is_stopped or _continue:
                try:
                    entry = await self.playlist.get_next_entry()
                except:
                    log.warning("Failed to get entry, retrying", exc_info=True)
                    self.loop.call_later(0.1, self.play)
                    return
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use an async context manager like that, try this instead

```py
async with self._play_lock:
    ...
```